# Active transformation to switch basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was wondering how I could construct a $2\times 2$ active transformation matrix which would switch the basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, by $\{e_1,e_2\}$ you mean the standard basis $e_1=(1,0)$, $e_2=(0,1)$, and you want to find the matrix associated to a linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(e_1)=e_2$ and $f(e_2)=e_1$.

This is quite simple, since such linear function is unique and its associated matrix (with respect to this basis) is just $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ (why?).
You can easily compute that this matrix "switches" $e_1$ and $e_2$.

Comment: ah yes this makes sense, the context I read it in confused me a lot but I see why this is so simple.